# What happens to the graph of $f$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm trying to figure out what happens to the graph of $f$ in the following to situations:

- $f = f(|x|)$
- $f = f(\frac{1}{x})$

For the first, I know if $f = |f(x)|$ then the points below the $x$ axis are reflected above the $x$ axis. However, I can't wrap by head around what happens when the absolute value bars are moved inside. For the second, how can this transformation produce a consistent effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should definitely employ some tools like your graphing calculator or (perhaps better?) [www.desmos.com](http://www.desmos.com) -- a free tool -- to get a feel for these strange (and the more normal) transformations.

Do this for a few different types of functions. I'll illustrate what the screen looks like:

[image: From Desmos]

So above you can see I've plotted the original function along with the two transformations.

Go here: [The Graph Above on Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/jbol3zhblt)

There you can change f(x) = sin(x) to something else -- try even and odd functions, different periods, things like x*sin(x), discrete things like [x] (greatest integer), etc. It will automatically update to show the transformations.

You can turn off/change color/style by clicking the colored circles next to the function definitions.

What happens given f and then $f\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)$?

$f\left(\frac{1}{\left|x\right|}\right)$?

$f\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)$?

All of this is to say, PLAY!

Comment: I've been trying different functions, but I still can't see a pattern for f(1/x).

Comment: As K. Jiang said, there isn't really anything consistent to say, is there? 

One might consider talking about particular types of functions such as:

polynomial functions $p(x)=a_nx_n+\dots+a_1x_1+a_0$ like $x, x^2+1$, etc. you will get a rational function of the form 
$p(1/x)=a_n(1/x)^n+\dots+a_1(1/x)+a_0$

What does it do for sin(x) and cos(x) [very important for thinking about calculus ideas later -- hard]

Answer (score 2):

For the first function definition, nothing happens to the graph of $f$ for $x \geq 0.$ The graph of $f(x)$ for $x \leq 0$ is simply reflected across the $y-$axis to produce the whole graph of $f(x).$

For the second function, there really isn't any consistent transformation effect. Basically, you could say that the graph of $f(x)$ for $x \geq 0$ is reflected across $x = 1$ and compressed and stretched to fill the right half-plane. For $x \leq 0,$ the graph of $f(x)$ is reflected across $x = -1$ and compressed and stretched accordingly to fill the left half-plane.

Comment: In your second sentence, do you mean x<= 0?